# Is it possible to display multiple rows of data from SQLite into one single text variable? Tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I want to display multiple rows of data in a Label.
I tried to use a StringVar and set it to the multiple rows of data  but only displayed one row.
Is it possible? If so, how???

Here's what I tried:

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

window = Tk()

textvar = StringVar()
label = Label(window, textvariable=textvar)
label.pack()

con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = con.cursor()
data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
for i in data:
    textvar.set(i)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing the for loop to `textvar.set('\n'.join(data))`.

Comment: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found`

Comment: Then try `textvar.set('\n'.join(str(x) for x in data))`.

Comment: @acw1668, Thanks again!